# Question about the proof of independence of $\bar Y$ and $S^2$ for normal random samples

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, independence

For an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution $Y_1,...,Y_n$, the proof below shows that $\bar Y$ and $S^2$ are independent. My confusion comes from the fact that the author defines $U = B^T Y$, and the fact that $U = a + B^TY$ has distribution $N(a+B^T\mu, B^T\Omega B)$ (shown earlier in the book).

In the very last equation, the author uses the fact that $B^TB = I_n$ (stated in the second paragraph) to show that $\sum_{j=1}^nY_j^2=Y^TY=Y^TB^TBY=U^TU$. This seems to imply that $U = BY$ and not $B^TY$?

[image]

Comment: $B^\prime$ is a (normalized) [Helmert matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20matrix%20helmert).  When you have questions about matrix algebra, usually they can quickly and insightfully be answered by carrying out the calculations yourself for small dimensions.  $n=3$ ought to show you what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that $B^T$ is orthogonal, so $B^TB = BB^T = I$ and the last line holds.